# dotnet build failing in docker container using dotnet:2.1-sdk

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to add docker support to an existing ASP.NET Core 2.1 web application. It is failing during the `dotnet build` command, saying it cannot load shared library `kernel32.dll` and `libkernel32.dll`.  I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN ls -la
WORKDIR /src/WebRazorPages
RUN ls -la
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
RUN dotnet build --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebRazorPages.dll"]
```

It runs up to the dotnet build step without error, but then fails with an issue finding shared files as part of the targets file build process. Full output shown below:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: WebRazorPages, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>You are working with a preview version of the .NET Core SDK. You can define the SDK version via a global.json file in the current project. More at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869452
1>docker exec -i 44ded24c4cef1fbf9539449dac737aa39e7c255d6a4da9f09106fb689be2a769 /bin/bash -c "if PID=$(pidof -x dotnet); then kill $PID; fi"
1>WebRazorPages -> C:\dev\github\eShopOnWeb\src\WebRazorPages\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.eShopWeb.RazorPages.dll
1>WebRazorPages -> C:\dev\github\eShopOnWeb\src\WebRazorPages\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.eShopWeb.RazorPages.Views.dll
1>docker build -f "C:\dev\github\eShopOnWeb\src\WebRazorPages\Dockerfile" -t microsoft.eshopweb.razorpages "C:\dev\github\eShopOnWeb\src"
1>Sending build context to Docker daemon  35.46MB
1>
1>Step 1/17 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
1> ---> 083ca6a642ea
1>Step 2/17 : WORKDIR /app
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> b0c93ee1eca8
1>Step 3/17 : EXPOSE 80
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> 76e2ed0decb7
1>Step 4/17 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
1> ---> 1f63052e44c2
1>Step 5/17 : WORKDIR /src
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> 1c80bb67fe43
1>Step 6/17 : COPY . .
1> ---> d97c2bf3a900
1>Step 7/17 : RUN ls -la
1> ---> Running in ecb2727f2649
1>total 24
1>drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4096 May 21 14:37 .
1>drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4096 May 21 14:37 ..
1>drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 May 19 19:11 ApplicationCore
1>drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 May 19 20:48 Infrastructure
1>drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 May 19 22:18 Web
1>drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 May 21 14:37 WebRazorPages
1>Removing intermediate container ecb2727f2649
1> ---> 01618f215b1a
1>Step 8/17 : WORKDIR /src/WebRazorPages
1>Removing intermediate container 7d812e8c1852
1> ---> b0c821c0cd10
1>Step 9/17 : RUN ls -la
1> ---> Running in 7055f247949a
1>total 100
1>drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 May 21 14:37 .
1>drwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4096 May 21 14:37 ..
1>-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   36 Oct 24  2017 .bowerrc
1>-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  261 Apr  3 14:35 Constants.cs
1>drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 24  2017 Controllers
1>-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  475 May 21 14:37 Dockerfile
1>drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 24  2017 Extensions
1>drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 24  2017 Interfaces
1>drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 May 19 21:36 Pages
1>-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1644 May 21 14:35 Program.cs
1>drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May 19 22:18 Properties
1>drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 24  2017 Services
1>-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 6297 May 19 21:11 Startup.cs
1>drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr  3 14:35 ViewComponents
1>drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 24  2017 ViewModels
1>-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  915 May 21 13:45 WebRazorPages.csproj
1>-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  388 May 21 13:45 WebRazorPages.csproj.user
1>-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  178 Oct 24  2017 appsettings.Development.json
1>-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  113 Oct 24  2017 appsettings.json
1>drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 May 21 13:59 bin
1>-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  207 Oct 24  2017 bower.json
1>-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  628 Oct 24  2017 bundleconfig.json
1>drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 May 21 13:59 obj
1>drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Oct 24  2017 wwwroot
1>Removing intermediate container 7055f247949a
1> ---> 74b0f03086c2
1>Step 10/17 : RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
1> ---> Running in 33852929709e
1>  Restoring packages for /src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj...
1>  Restoring packages for /src/ApplicationCore/ApplicationCore.csproj...
1>  Installing Ardalis.GuardClauses 1.2.3.
1>  Generating MSBuild file /src/ApplicationCore/obj/ApplicationCore.csproj.nuget.g.props.
1>  Generating MSBuild file /src/ApplicationCore/obj/ApplicationCore.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
1>  Restore completed in 1.01 sec for /src/ApplicationCore/ApplicationCore.csproj.
1>  Restoring packages for /src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj...
1>  Installing System.Security.Cryptography.Cng 4.4.0.
1>  Installing System.Numerics.Vectors 4.4.0.
1>  Installing System.Buffers 4.4.0.
1>  Generating MSBuild file /src/Infrastructure/obj/Infrastructure.csproj.nuget.g.props.
1>  Generating MSBuild file /src/Infrastructure/obj/Infrastructure.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
1>  Restore completed in 2.85 sec for /src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj.
1>  Installing System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.5.0-preview1-26216-02.
1>  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing System.Buffers 4.5.0-preview1-26216-02.
1>  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing System.Text.Encodings.Web 4.5.0-preview1-26216-02.
1>  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets 0.1.1646902.
1>  Installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 2.1.0-preview1-final.
1>  Generating MSBuild file /src/WebRazorPages/obj/WebRazorPages.csproj.nuget.g.props.
1>  Generating MSBuild file /src/WebRazorPages/obj/WebRazorPages.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
1>  Restore completed in 2.49 sec for /src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj.
1>Removing intermediate container 33852929709e
1> ---> 0e020cc66427
1>Step 11/17 : RUN dotnet build --no-restore -c Release -o /app
1> ---> Running in da8aed1609f1
1>Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.177.53362 for .NET Core
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
1>
1>  You are working with a preview version of the .NET Core SDK. You can define the SDK version via a global.json file in the current project. More at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869452
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018: The "KillAppInsideContainer" task failed unexpectedly. [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libkernel32.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.Prerequisites.DockerForWindowsRunningPrerequisite.WaitNamedPipe(String name, Int32 timeout) [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.Prerequisites.DockerForWindowsRunningPrerequisite.EvaluateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.Prerequisites.CompositePrerequisite.EvaluateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Tasks.ContainerBuildTask.HandleExceptionAsync(Exception ex, ContainerBuildTaskContext context) [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Tasks.ContainerBuildTask.ExecuteAsync(ContainerBuildTaskContext context) [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Tasks.ContainerBuildTask.Execute() [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018: The "KillAppInsideContainer" task failed unexpectedly. [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libkernel32.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.Prerequisites.DockerForWindowsRunningPrerequisite.WaitNamedPipe(String name, Int32 timeout) [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.Prerequisites.DockerForWindowsRunningPrerequisite.EvaluateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.Prerequisites.CompositePrerequisite.EvaluateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Tasks.ContainerBuildTask.HandleExceptionAsync(Exception ex, ContainerBuildTaskContext context) [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Tasks.ContainerBuildTask.ExecuteAsync(ContainerBuildTaskContext context) [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Tasks.ContainerBuildTask.Execute() [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/0.1.1646902/build/Container.targets(188,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [/src/WebRazorPages/WebRazorPages.csproj]
1>    0 Warning(s)
1>    1 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.66
1>The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet build --no-restore -c Release -o /app' returned a non-zero code: 1
1>C:\Users\steve\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\0.1.1646902\build\Container.targets(212,5): error : An error occurred while attempting to build Docker image.
1>Done building project "WebRazorPages.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Why is it unable to find the file when it's clearly present in the folder and was just used successfully to perform a `dotnet restore`?

**UPDATE**
The error suggested setting LD_DEBUG, so I did, and it yields this information:

```
        21:     calling init: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so.2
        21:
        21:     find library=kernel32.dll.so [0]; searching
        21:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
        21:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib:/usr/lib              (system search path)
        21:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kernel32.dll.so
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kernel32.dll.so
        21:       trying file=/lib/kernel32.dll.so
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/kernel32.dll.so
        21:
        21:     find library=libkernel32.dll.so [0]; searching
        21:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
        21:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib:/usr/lib              (system search path)
        21:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkernel32.dll.so
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkernel32.dll.so
        21:       trying file=/lib/libkernel32.dll.so
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/libkernel32.dll.so
        21:
        21:     find library=kernel32.dll [0]; searching
        21:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
        21:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib:/usr/lib              (system search path)
        21:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kernel32.dll
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kernel32.dll
        21:       trying file=/lib/kernel32.dll
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/kernel32.dll
        21:
        21:     find library=libkernel32.dll [0]; searching
        21:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
        21:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib:/usr/lib              (system search path)
        21:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkernel32.dll
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkernel32.dll
        21:       trying file=/lib/libkernel32.dll
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/libkernel32.dll
        21:
        21:     find library=Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll [0]; searching
        21:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
        21:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib:/usr/lib              (system search path)
        21:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:       trying file=/lib/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:
        21:     find library=Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll [0]; searching
        21:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
        21:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib:/usr/lib              (system search path)
        21:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:       trying file=/lib/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:
        21:     find library=Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll [0]; searching
        21:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
        21:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib:/usr/lib              (system search path)
        21:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:       trying file=/lib/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:
        21:     find library=Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll [0]; searching
        21:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
        21:      search path=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/lib:/usr/lib              (system search path)
        21:       trying file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:       trying file=/lib/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:       trying file=/usr/lib/Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.amd64.dll
        21:
```

Comment: Has this ever worked?  What container are you trying to use?

Comment: I’m trying to “dockerize” a working ASPNET Core 2.1 solution. Hence I’m using the 2.1 images to build it. But no, it hasn’t yet ever worked.

Comment: Has that image just been updated?  I'd try a brand new app with [dotnet new] to test the image itself, that kernel error seems fishy...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I used Visual Studio 2017 (Preview) to Add > Docker Support it added a package reference to the web project for `microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools`. Removing this reference got me past the error and I was ultimately able to dockerize the application at that point. It wasn't immediately obvious that this package had been added since the online documentation for VS's behavior stated only that it added a Dockerfile, not that it otherwise messed with the project.